Openstack cloud host cannot be accessed on the vxlan network http://169.254.n.n, but external network can
I used OVS network and enabled BR. The specific command is
ovs-vsctl add br br ens192
ovs-vsctl add port br ens192 ens192

Two networks were created in the dashboard. One is the vxlan network (internal), and the other is the flat network (external).
network topology
Cloud hosts running on vxlan may not receive metadata information for a long time. If using curl http://169.254.169.254 for a longer period of time, it will be accessed.
Is it possible that I used a virtual machine to run OpenStack?
the cloud-hosts-cirros-image-logs
In a flat network, it is normal. The log from the cloud host section of the vxlan network tells us that it is unable to access this cloud init：
udhcpc: sending discover
udhcpc: sending select for 10.0.0.140
udhcpc: lease of 10.0.0.140 obtained, lease time 86400
route: SIOCADDRT: File exists
WARN: failed: route add -net "0.0.0.0/0" gw "10.0.0.1"
OK
checking http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/instance-id
failed 1/20: up 2.31. request failed
failed 2/20: up 51.34. request failed
failed 3/20: up 100.37. request failed
failed 4/20: up 149.40. request failed
failed 5/20: up 198.42. request failed
failed 6/20: up 247.45. request failed
failed 7/20: up 296.48. request failed
failed 8/20: up 345.50. request failed
failed 9/20: up 394.53. request failed
failed 10/20: up 443.55. request failed
failed 11/20: up 492.58. request failed
failed 12/20: up 541.60. request failed
failed 13/20: up 590.62. request failed
failed 14/20: up 639.65. request failed
failed 15/20: up 688.67. request failed
failed 16/20: up 737.70. request failed
failed 17/20: up 786.72. request failed
failed 18/20: up 835.74. request failed
failed 19/20: up 884.77. request failed
failed 20/20: up 933.79. request failed
failed to read iid from metadata. tried 20
failed to get instance-id of datasource


openstack version Yoga

I found that I have some issues accessing the cloud host. I am accessing its floating IP,
Ping 192.168.10.197 is normal
17:47:32.991241 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 28797, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
controller > 192.168.101.197: ICMP echo request, id 5, seq 8, length 64
But accessing
Ssh 192.168.10.197 will report that the connection has been reset
17:41:59.195176 IP controller.52124 > 192.168.101.197.ssh: Flags [.], seq 42:1440, ack 1302, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 146919920 ecr 2974464], length 1398
